# Configuring squid to take the final destination url from an http header parameter

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, urlfetch

I would like to use Squid as a proxy for a Google App Engine based application (as we need to have a static outgoing ip, and GAE does not support that).
Also, I want to keep using urlfetch, so as not to do too much changes in the existing code.

The solution I want to implement is to install a Squid proxy, and direct all the urlfetch requests to this proxy by using the proxy url in the fetch request, and add some custom http header that will contain the final destination url.

Then, I want to configure Squid to take this custom header parameter from the request, and use it as the request url.
How do I configure this last part on Squid ?

(There may be many different urls, so configuring a separate port for each destination url is not an option).